# Why is the code (Python) giving error?

Tags: python, class, attributes, class-method

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Prisoners_Dilemma:


    def __init__(self,n,p):
        self.n = n
        self.p = p


    def decision_array(self):
        self.dict_dict = {}

        for i in range(1,self.n + 1):
            self.dict_dict[i] = []
            list_list = []

            for j in range(1,self.n):        
                #np.random.seed(j)
                self.r = np.random.uniform(0,1)

                if self.r > self.p:
                    q = 0

                else:
                    q = 1

                list_list.append(q)                
                self.dict_dict[i] = list_list

        return self.dict_dict


    def payoff(self):
        self.dict_dict_2 = {}

        for i in range(1,self.n + 1):
            self.dict_dict_2[i] = []
            list_list_2 = []
            list_list_3=[]

            for j in range(1, i):
                    list_list_2.append(self.dict_dict[j][i-2])

            for j in range(i + 1, self.n + 1):
                    list_list_2.append(self.dict_dict[j][i-1])



            list_list_2_np = np.array(list_list_2)
            against_i = np.sum(list_list_2_np)
            for_i = np.sum(self.dict_dict[i]) 

            if against_i == 0 and for_i == 0:
                payoff_i = 2

            elif against_i == 0 and for_i != 0:
                payoff_i = 5

            elif against_i != 0 and for_i == 0:
                payoff_i = -5

            else:
                payoff_i = -2

            list_list_3.append(payoff_i)

            self.dict_dict_2[i]=list_list_3

        return self.dict_dict_2


    def gameplay(self, N, initial_count):

        self.counter = initial_count

        for i in range(N):
            for j in range(1, self.n + 1):
                z = self.dict_dict_2[j]
                x = np.array(z)


                self.counter += np.sum(z)
        return self.counter

y = Prisoners_Dilemma(15,0.015)

print (y.gameplay(20,100))
```

In the above code, the compiler gives the error that instance has no attribute as dict_dict_2 even though its prefixed with self. Moreover, it is perfectly fine with dict_dict. For the sake of completeness I have included the whole code but the problem lies only in payoff and gameplay methods?

Answer (score 2):

`dict_dict_2` is *only* created in `payoff()`, therefore you *must* call it before attempting to call `gameplay()`.

Comment: could you then explain why dict_dict variable works (see payoff and decision_matrix) ?

Comment: It "works" by accident, because **you never access it**.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are only creating `self.dict_dict_2` variable in the `payoff` function, but in your logic where you are calling `gameplay()` function , you are not calling the `payoff()` function before accessing `dict_dict_2` , from the looks of it you are not calling that function anywhere at all.

Not sure what `dict_dict_2` holds, but the above is the reason why you are getting the issue, maybe you can move the initialization part of `dict_dict_2` to `__init__()` function , though that would not fix the complete issue, since you would still be trying to access `dict_dict_1[j]` which can error out if `j` is not a key in `dict_dict_2` .

Comment: could you then explain why no such problem with dict_dict variable??

Comment: You are not accessing `dict_dict` variable anywhere in gameplay at all, you try accessing that there (just do simple `print(self.dict_dict)`) and you will see the error for that as well

Comment: not in the gameplay. I invoked dict_dict in decision_matrix and used it in payoff without any special syntax, still it works fine and gives me the list (if you try running the code by commenting the gameplay part).

Comment: You are defining `dict_dict` in the starting of `decision_matrix` , the line for the definition is - `self.dict_dict = {}` , this defines the variable `dict_dict` inside `self` .